# Image with fixed size in procents on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have a bunch of images with different sizes. Each of them should be presented on the top part of the screen and must take the space in height equal to 60% of screen height.  Width of the image will be dependent on it's height to save initial proportions. I tried to use `weightsum` property in layout and `weight` property in `ImageView`, but I don't know what to put in the `height` property of my image view. If it is "wrap_content", every image resizes my ImageView and all mark-up crushes. 
Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can set the image's dimensions by code.
Just set the width with the weight_sum method and then do something like:

```
 WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 int screenHeight = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
 YOUR_VIEW.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (screenWidth * 0.6);
```

Please mind that you can do so only AFTER your ImageView has been drawn on screen - so calling it within the onCreate() method will not work.
You can either  call it delayed (postDelayed) or set a layout listener to one of your view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Also, doing it in onPostCreate() method is ok too.